# How to show multiple elements using onclick?

Tags: onclick, element, show

In my code, im using an onclick function to show an element with display:none. If I set a second element to display:none, how can i code the script to show both hidden elements onclick?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<a href="#" id="clickme" onclick="showStuff('element1'); return false;"></a>

<div id="element1" style="display:none;"></div>
<div id="element2" style="display:none;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function showStuff(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of IDs, use classes for your elements and show all elements with that class name on click (I am using jQuery):

```
<a href="#" id="click-me">Click Me</a>

<div class="elem" style="display:none;"></div>
<div class="elem" style="display:none;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#click-me').click(function() {
    $('.elem').show();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You gotta put the all elements on a div container, and when you set the display to none, all elements will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

**Without jQuery**

```
 <input type="button" value="test element1" onclick="showStuff('element1')">
<input type="button" value="test element2" onclick="showStuff('element2')">

<div id="element1" style="display:none;"></div>
<div id="element2" style="display:none;"></div>
```

js code :

```
showStuff = function(id){
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/o1t09j0d/)